# Skype Web SDK Running Locally

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

is it possible to run the Skype Web SDK locally without internet access to the Skype CDN?

I have tried downloading https://swx.cdn.skype.com/shared/v/1.1.23.0/SkypeBootstrap.min.js which results in this being downloaded 
https://latest-swx.cdn.skype.com/jLync/master_0.4.232/sdk.js

Comment: Look at this link: http://blog.thoughtstuff.co.uk/2015/07/how-to-skype-web-sdk-development-without-having-all-the-server-pre-requisites-in-place/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Pavel, though from having a quick read i'm not sure if this will be a permanent solution if the tokens need to be renewed regularly.

Comment: You can do this as mentioned in this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39631648/skypesdk-video-and-audio-issue-mediarelayaccesstoken-not-found/39640713#39640713)

Comment: @Lewis2018 Did you figure this out? I have the same issue and cannot access the cdn website at work

Answer (score 0):

The Skype Web SDK is javascript code that is downloaded from the Skype CDN. The files that you mention in your question are correct - the bootstrapper downloads the actual code.
Is there a reason you would like to run it locally without internet? How would you sign in to a Skype for Business server (which is what the Skype for Business SDK does for you) if you plan to run without internet?

Comment: The system i am planning on deploying Skype for Business to will be a totally isolated for security reasons and won't be able to access the CDN. Users will access the skype for business server using thin clients on which no applications can be installed which is why i was looking at developing an app to be hosted on a local web server.

Comment: I thought as long as i had a local Skype for Business server installed i wouldn't need access to the internet? As it only be for communication between local domain users

Comment: @Sid - Microsoft  If you do not have access to this site at work is there a way that you can get the javascript to your machine locally?