# SkypeSDK Video and audio issue - mediaRelayAccessToken not found

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm having problems with adding an audio or a video service to a coversation.
The chat service works fine for me.
When I add a video or an audio service I get following error:

```
Error: GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113925534802/communication/mediaRelayAccessToken failed: 404
{
  [functions]: ,
  __proto__: { },
  code: "RequestFailed",
  description: "GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113925534802/communication/mediaRelayAccessToken failed: 404",
  message: "GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113925534802/communication/mediaRelayAccessToken failed: 404",
  name: "Error",
  req: { },
  rsp: { },
  stack: "Error: GET /ucwa/oauth/v1/applications/113925534802/communication/mediaRelayAccessToken failed: 404
at process (https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:8079:29)
at Anonymous function (https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:8018:29)
at Anonymous function (https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:1714:25)
at map (https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:1331:25)
at decompose (https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:8017:25)
at Anonymous function (https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:8007:29)
at handle (https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:2220:33)
at Anonymous function (https://swx.cdn.skype.com/build2015/v5/SDK-build.js:698:25)"
}
```

The Skype For Business Plugin is installed and works fine.
A Skype Edge server is currently not installed. 
I'm using Internet Explorer 11.

The error occurs with the Skype Web SDK On Prem Sample from Microsoft as well as on my own website.

When I try to add video or audio for the second time to the same conversation i dont get any error message at all, but it still doesn't work. The request doesnt show up in the dev tools nor in fiddler. I'm using the latest version of the Skype SDk bootstrapper.

Both clients and server are in the same subnet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. Not sure how it happens, but the sdk has troubles to fetch or apply the media config.
You can use the this workaround:

Following line 18,892 in the debug version of the sdk, comment out both calls:

`uninit();
throw error;`

in the function `init()` of the section `MediaConfig`. Resulting in:

`function init() {
                        pcMediaConfig = mediaPlugin.createComponent({
                            type: 'MediaPlatformConfig',
                            hide: true,
                            inproc: false
                        });
                        pcMediaConfig.event(onPluginComponentEvent);
                        pcMediaConfig.state.changed(function (state) {
                            log('pcMediaConfig.state = ' + state);
                        });
                        var p = pcMediaConfig.load().then(getMediaConfig).then(setMediaConfig).then(null, function (error) {
                            log('MediaConfig::init rejected');
                            //uninit();
                            //throw error;
                        });
                        return p;
                    }`

Therefore you have to download the bootstrapper and the sdk to permanently apply the patch. To do this just fetch both in the debug version (bootstrapper version 1.2.5) and replace in function `onConfig(config)` line 48

`}, config.corsScript && (scriptAttributes.crossOrigin = ""), loader.loadScript(getPackageUrl(config), null, handleError, scriptAttributes);`

with

`}, config.corsScript && (scriptAttributes.crossOrigin = ""), loader.loadScript("./scripts/SkypeSDK.js", null, handleError, scriptAttributes);`

or your equivalent path

Answer (score 1):

This is currently a limitation of the Skype Web SDK: it has a dependency on the mediaRelayAccessToken to proceed with audio/video calls. The dev team is aware of this issue and it may be fixed in a future release of Skype Web SDK.

The hacky way recommended above is basically to allow the SDK to continue the call upon missing mediaRelayAccessToken, so it may let you bypass the issue.

The media relay access token is returned by an edge server, so you may also try to deploy an edge server to work around this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Isn't it kinda weird that you need an Edge Server to make it work properly or am i getting something wrong?

Comment: Edge is going through the ORTC route while IE is using media plugin; so it's 2 different stories.

Comment: Tom: the Skype Web SDK has been updated to relax the dependency on mras. You may want to try again and if it's still not working, indicate the sdk version used (paste the uri here). Thanks.

Comment: I got another problem with the Conversation Control... I cant accept incoming calls anymore. It used to work a few weeks ago. But now nothing happens when i get an incoming call. Web -> Client works fine. Web -> Web does not. When the other participant ends the call i just get the message that i missed a call. This problem occurs with my own Web App and with the official samples from Microsoft. Any idea what the problem could be?